# Headless Wordpress redirect front-page to login page

Tags: redirect, htaccess

Is there any way to redirect `https://example.com/` to `https://example.com/admin` with `.htaccess` ?

I'm using WordPress only for the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your `.htaccess` file *before* the WordPress front-controller try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /admin [R,L]
```

This redirects `https://example.com/` to `https://domain.com/admin`. This is a temporary (302) redirect.

Comment: Thanks ! It works :))

Comment: Hope you don't mind a followup question. I can well believe this works, 'cause I've seen similar things before. My question is "why does it work?" My naive reading of `^$` is that it would match nothing; instead, it apparently matches everything. But how? Feel free to point me at webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @LorenRosen "reading of `^$` is that it would match nothing" - Well, it matches an _empty_ URL-path, ie. a request for the document root only. It doesn't match "everything". It doesn't match `https://example.com/something` for instance. The `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (first argument) matches the URL-path only. In `.htaccess` the first slash is omitted. So it matches against an empty URL-path and not `/` (a single slash).